# how to post to page wall as admin user not as page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

I know how to post to page wall/comment/like by graph api.As a post sample i use in this way -

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.status=='connected') {
     if (response.authResponse.accessToken) 
     {
        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken; 
        FB.api('/'+Page_id+'/feed?access_token='+token+'&message='+message, 'POST', function(response) { ......rest of the codes.....
```

but because i am admin user of my page, its posting as page not as admin user which is me.also same way when i comment,like a page post same behaviour. I searched some posts which have not answered my answer yet.i also found that its a fb bug reported here -

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/334877786593553/
```

but fb response for the bug is not a solution!.So any alternative other than facebook dialog(fb.ui) and research on it are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/239552896186049 actually doesn't make sense, let me report the bug. :)

Comment: I have report a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/647340981958249

Comment: That's funny they assigned that bug as a low priority and hide comments for that page!